# leakage current as a function of the depletion width

Tags: semiconductor-physics

How does the leakage current behave with an increasing reverse voltage applied to a semiconductor?
Will it increase too or is it independent from the depletion with respectively voltage? I can argue in both ways but which is correct?
On the hand I think it should decrease as the depletion width is wider and therefore also the leakage current faces a higher barrier.
On the other hand I guess it should increase as a higher voltage will also drive the leakage current.

Comment: What does Shockley's diode equation say?

Comment: Practical diodes' leakage may depend on things like contaminants on the die surface or packaging materials that have nothing to do with depletion width.

Comment: Where does the leakage current come from? Relate that to an increasing depletion width...

Comment: So there is no relationship between leakage current and depletion width?